# Measure entropy of a binary matrix

Tags: compression, entropy

I`ve a 100*100 binary matrix the probability of each pixel given by this relation : 
[image]

i want to know how to calculate the entropy of this image .

Answer (score 0):

According to the given conditions, the probability for each entry in the matrix can be calculated accordingly.

For example, because s(1,1)=0, s(1,2)=0, s(2,1)=0, then you can calculate P(s(2,2)=0), and P(s(2,2)=1) using the theorem.

After you calculate all the probability for all entries, then you can start to calculate the entropy of this image by calculating the expected value.

Comment: after calculating the probability of '0','1' of each pixel in the matrix 
to get the probability of '0' it`ll be :
int probablityOfZero=1;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
probablityOfZero = probablityOfZero* p0[i,j]; // P0[i,j] = probablity of zero of pixel(i,j)
}}
that is right ?! 
sorry for bad English

Comment: The calculation of probability is dependent on the given table of conditional probability. I don't think the codes you give here can accurately get the correct probability.

Comment: now i realized why i was wrong as each bit is dependent on the others so i couldn't calculate with this way . 
so i want to use extended Huffman to encode this matrix 
now i could calculate probability of one , zero for each pixel 
put to use extended Huffman i want to know probability of 0 over all pixels so how can i calculate it ?!

Comment: i`ve applied extended huffman on this data with 4 bits per symbol  and get compresion ratio 1.3 (put i`ve calculated the probablity direct from the given data)
now i want to calculate it using the table to avoid sending the Huffman tree to the decoder 
the main problem i face :
how to calculate the probability of symbol like 00010 
any help !! 
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Entropy is given by the formula:   `-Sum(PlogP)`

Where log is the base 2 logarithm and P is the probability of the information.